# Equivalent typeset -n options for HP/SOL

Tags: shell, unix, solaris, ksh

This is a simplified portion from a much larger script. I am using i as a conter to loop through a set of strings.

I have multiple strings "word1 word2 word3 word4 .....wordx" that I am looping through

```
i=1
typeset "STRING$i=`echo $string | cut -d' ' -f1-50`"
typeset -n NEWVAR="STRING$i"
do_stuff_here_w_NEWVAR
done
```

This works great on Linux, but my HP and SOL boxes do not like the typeset-n...what can i do here instead of -n for HP or Solaris?
When i run nameref on my boxes i get nameref:not found

Comment: for solaris, see if you can find ksh93 or dtksh. Namesrefs is not supported in ksh88, which is the default ksh for those 2 OSs. good luck. (Not sure about HP).

Answer (score 1):

The ksh88 is the default ksh in Solaris, HP-UX, and AIX. But ksh88 should have available arrays of variables:

```
#/usr/bin/ksh
typeset -i cnt=0

yourarray[$cnt]='word1'
((cnt = cnt + 1))
yourarray[$cnt]='word666'

echo ${yourarray[0]}
word1

echo ${yourarray[1]}
word666

echo ${yourarray[2]}
    # nothing
```